# check whether entered date time is between the range of 2 datetime values

Tags: php, mysql, between

I have table which contains 2 columns startdate and enddate for storing the start and end time of fun program in a particular venue.(Both columns are having format of datetime-format is 'Y-m-d H:i:s').When a user creates `a program within this time limit` or `the end time of the program lies within the time limit but not the start time` or `the start time lies within the time limit but not the end time`,the program should not be inserted into the table showing an alert.I have written the query like this.But it doesn't work properly.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_venue WHERE venue_id='id' AND
((venue_start_datetime BETWEEN 'entered starttime' AND 'entered end time')
AND (venue_stop_datetime BETWEEN 'entered starttime' AND 'entered end time'))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: > and < operations work on dates

Comment: @DiMono Hav used that.but it doesnt work perfectly in some cases

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what data type the column is? IF it's varchar that wouldn't still work would it? If you have your columns set ast DATETIME it will work.

Comment: In what cases doesn't it work? Is it ignoring the hours and minutes or something?

Comment: @Keeleon if the start time is before the start time in database or if end time is greater than end date in databse.If the start date and end date lies within the limit,it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_venue 
WHERE venue_id='id' AND
'entered starttime' >= venue_start_datetime
AND 'entered end time' <= venue_stop_datetime
AND 'entered starttime' <= 'entered end time'
```

Answer (score 0):

You jast have to test if the entered startdate is between start and enddate or the entererd enddate is between start and enddate

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_venue WHERE venue_id='id' AND
('entered starttime' BETWEEN venue_start_datetime AND venue_stop_datetime
OR 'entered endtime' BETWEEN venue_start_datetime AND venue_stop_datetime)
```